# Going through files in a directory & performing actions on them given date range as a parameter to go through the files between the dates specified?

Tags: bash, parsing, logging, awk, logfile

I have a directory which contains access_log files for an altassian product. The files are named as ***access_log.2017-11-02*** an example. I have log parser written in bash which I am using to parse all the data to a .csv file but I am unable to think of a way so that if I specify a date range as a parameter the parser would only look at the files between those dates for eg: between ***2017-11-02*** and ***access_log.2017-11-20***. I have written the log parser in bash and giving my code down below. Any help would be appreciated.

PS. I am very new to bash so I apologize for the mess in the bash file.
Also I am using a bash port for windows.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=C:/Users/userid/Desktop/UAT_log_files/*
for f in $FILES 
do
echo "Processing $f file.."
sed 's|[[[,]||g' $f >>$f.temp

LOG="$f.temp"
echo "Line Number,clientip,requestid,user,date,request,method,response,bytes,request_time,referrer,HTTP_Client & session_id" > $f.csv

< $LOG awk  '{if(length($13)>100) $13=substr($13,1,100);print NR-0 "," $1","$2","$3","$4","$6","$7" "$8" "$9","$10","$11" , " $12", " $13" ,  " $14"  " $15"  " $16" " $17" " $18" " $19" " $20" " $21" " $22" " $23" " $24" " $25" " $26" " $27" " $28}' >> $f.csv

rm $FILES.temp 
done
echo "clientip , requestid , user , date , request , method , response , bytes , request_time , referrer , HTTP_Client & session_id " > $FILESMainlog.csv
cat $FILES.csv >> Mainlog_temp.csv
rm .csv
echo "Deleting the temporary files now.."
rm $FILES.csv
echo "fixing the date time format"
awk -f redate.awk mainlog_temp.csv>mainlog.csv
sed 's/--date ::/date/g' mainlog.csv > new.csv ; mv new.csv mainlog.csv
rm mainlog_temp.csv
echo "Done! The file mainlog.csv has been created in the current directory"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `bash` [**range expansion**](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) of the form

```
{<START>..<END>}
```

For example

```
for file in "C:/Users/manishj/Desktop/UAT_log_files/access_log.2017-11-"{02..19}
# Above expands as access_log.2017-11-02,access_log.2017-11-03 and so.
do
  #required operation on "$file"
done
```

---

**Edit**

If range expansion doesn't work on the Windows port of bash, then use a `c-style` for-loop

```
for((i=2;i<=19;i++)) # for files 02 to 19
do
file="C:/Users/manishj/Desktop/UAT_log_files/access_log.2017-11-$(printf "%02d" $i)"
# Above, $file expands as access_log.2017-11-02,access_log.2017-11-03 and so.
# Do operation with "$file", Make sure you put it in double quotes.
done
```

Here we employ bash [**command substitution**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

**Edit 2**

If `c style` for loops too are not allowed then go for a traditional `while loop`

```
no=2
while [ $no -le "19" ]
do
file="C:/Users/manishj/Desktop/UAT_log_files/access_log.2017-11-$(printf "%02d" $no)"
    # Above, $file expands as access_log.2017-11-02,access_log.2017-11-03 and so.
    # Do operation with "$file", Make sure you put it in double quotes.
no=$((no+1)) # incrementing no
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the date part of a string. (It is assumed that it's an access log.)

```
extractDate() { sed 's/[^\.]*\.//' <(echo $1); }
```

Convert date to timestamp.

```
toStamp() { date --date="$1" +%s; }
```

Check if date is between bound.

```
# [$1, $2): bound
# $3 current date

isBetween() {
    [[ `toStamp $1` -le `toStamp $3` ]]&&\
    [[ `toStamp $2` -gt `toStamp $3` ]]&&\
    true||\
    false
}
```

Test.

```
test() { `isBetween $1 $2 $3` && echo true || echo false; }

test 2010 2020 2009
test 2009 2020 2009
test 2020 2020 2009
test 2008 2020 2009
test 2021 2020 2009
```

Comment: I am not quite sure how to implement this with my present code, sorry i am very new to bash

Comment: Alright then, for the functions, it would be enough to just copy paste them.

Comment: alirght, what next

Comment: I try to figure it out, but your cod is very messy -.-'. No offense. :)

Comment: sorry about that, really new to bash

Comment: so you want only process files with proper dates at the processing section, that's all?

Comment: yeah, i want to process files in a given directory between a date, say 2017-09-02 to 2017-09-05 where the dates are the extensions for the files.

Comment: So I refactor the code to be extensible, and I'll tell you the reasons if you are interested.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do inside of the loop and outside of it, so this needs to be edited. Upper and lower bounds need to be added to the proper place. Code is not tested btw.

Comment: alright! I'll take a look! Thank you for your help, looks to be working so far